# Good Way to Stuff Dry Hops into Dry Hop Bag

Tags: hops, secondary-fermentation, dry-hop

I'm new to brewing and I recently transferred some brew from secondary that had dry hopping into a corney keg.

I think everything went fine, but I really had a hard time stuffing the dry hops into the slim bag I had.  It took me longer to do and the bag was out in the air while I was doing this, so I was worried about contamination.

So the question is, what is a good way to stuff the hops into the slim bag or should I use a different bag?

Comment: Hmm, I just put my hops straight in.  Why bag it?

Answer (score 4):

You probably won't get a contamination from that, but i can suggest a device:

Get a 2 litters coke pet bottle

Cut out top and bottom to make a tube

Cut it on it's length so you can roll it on itself, diminishing the diameter

Insert the rolled tube on your bag, let it free so it go back to the original diameter.

Put hops in, slide tube out.

Finally, let me know if you like it so I can patent the invention.  :)

Comment: That's actually a really clever idea. Bravo!

Comment: very good idea...  I really like it.  I'm stuffing again soon and I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I do.. 
http://www.brewgeeks.com/dry-hop.html

Don't worry about contamination.  Hops are naturally resistant and the alchohol present should keep things relatively safe.